# How to make my line manager approve my internal transfer

Tags: job-change, internal-transfer

I am planning to move to another department in my company. In my company, internal transfer need to fulfill two requirements:

1. Work in the current position for more than 18 months (I have worked in my current position for two years)
2. Give a sufficient reason for internal transfer (my transfer reason is for changing working content because of my interests)

I think I have fulfilled above 2 requirements. Currently, our product has been entered into stable state. My leaving would not impact our project.

I have told my line manager about my thought of internal transfer. When I want to talk with him  about this, he often delays the conversation, and has been doing so for at least 1.5 months.

Is there any good way to make my line manager approve my internal transfer quickly?

Comment: union,do you mean something like organization ?  I am in a company now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: make sure that "personal interests" is an approved internal transfer reason, according to HR and company policy. Just because you think you've met the criteria doesn't mean that you have in the eyes of your management.

If you can get confirmation from HR (or even the same manager) that your transfer reason meets company standards, you have only a couple of options:

1. **Press for Specifics**
   Next time you discuss it with your manager, ask for the *specific* reason(s) he thinks you don't meet the criteria or that he doesn't seem willing to approve the transfer. If he provides some details, then that can be the start of a more meaningful discussion about creating a plan to meet his requirements to approve the transfer. If this is unsuccessful, check other company resources: HR, or possibly the next level of management if you're willing to risk creating more tension between you and your manager (which may make both the internal transfer and having him as a future reference more difficult).
2. **Move On**
   If those are unsuccessful, you may not have much recourse besides polishing up your resume and seeking work elsewhere.

No matter what you decide, make sure your desires are clearly understood, in as positive a way as possible. Make it known that you are willing to stay in your current position for a while to train your replacement and properly hand off your duties.

Comment: hello, thanks you for your helpful comment. actually my transfer reason was guided by the LM from the department I want join in . lastest status is my current LM say that currently our department transfer policy is frozen. so my next step is the option2 Move on?

Comment: @dida08 Unfortunately that sounds like that's the case. That response seems pretty clear and inflexible. If you *really* like the company AND *really* want to work for the other manager AND he/she *really* wants you, the two of you may be able to work out a hiring process that isn't treated as an internal transfer. You could check with the other manager and see if he/she can hire you the same way an external candidate would be hired. This is likely to ruffle some feathers, but you have the right to pursue the career you want (IMHO).

Comment: I think so too. I am clear now , thanks for your advices

Comment: @dida08 By the way, you should consider upvoting answers here that you find useful (the up arrow on the left), and if you think that one really answers your question, you should "Accept" it by clicking on the hollow checkmark that's below the vote buttons. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) Although there's no pressure to do so if you don't think the answers are useful or that they don't answer your question. You can upvote multiple answers, but only accept one.

Comment: sorry for my not well-considered, done now

Comment: @dida08 No worries. Since you have low rep on the site I didn't know if you knew about it. And again, you shouldn't feel pressured to accept or vote on an answer just because it's there - it's entirely up to you to decide if an answer actually answers your question and is useful.

Comment: yes, I am new comer here, nice and friendly advices for me.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the two reasons, the first one is quantifiable and you satisfy this condition, No "if"s or "but"s about that.

The second requirement is very, very subjective. "Sufficient reason to do internal transfer" : Sufficient for whom ? Obviously you think that you wanting to work on a different project is sufficient for you. But think about the employer. They will be losing someone who can be very critical supporting the mature product you mentioned. If you leave, they need to hire someone new or someone internally transfer, who knows nothing about the product. So, his or her first few weeks, if not months are wasted resources for the company. And you in your new role will need some ramp-up time. Another resource waste. Unless your new department thinks that you are the next thing after sliced bread for their project, it is very hard to justify this second requirement. After all company is paying you your salary to perform the work they want you to perform. Not hop from one project to the other because you are bored or changed interest in your current role.

Do not think it only from your point of view. Think from the company's angle too.

Comment: yes, definitely  you are right. I have also talked with my LM that I can stay in current position for a time to hand off properly.

Comment: also for an internal transfer there actually has to be an opening available in the other location

Comment: thanks for your detail and helpful analysis, yes, definitely  you are right. I have also talked with my LM that I can stay in current position for a time to hand off properly. in my opinion, the majority of the internal transfer cases will met the problems you mentioned.  I am wondering is there any good way to internal transfer successfully?

Comment: Find someone who know about the new product you just finished and willing to support it for the years to come. The learning curve for this person should not be too high as he/she will know a great deal about it and will take away the blow of your absence from ongoing support. Also you need to make a case, if possible, quantifiable with facts, that, your joining the new team will make them more effective, provide them a skill that they lack etc. After doing these, if you can not transfer, I'd look into my personal relationships with the management on both sides

Comment: @ MelBurslan, yes, really practical  advices.